# Guide to DFT functionals

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory, ab-initio

Having recently begun studying Quantum and computational chemistry in depth... I am looking for a manual, text, or guide of any form that could explain the basic formulations and potential of the Functionals used in DFT.

My focus lies primarily on their physical significance, preferably derived mathematically...

Could someone kindly help me out with this...

Comment: I would suggest a book entitled "[A Chemist's Guide to Density Functional Theory](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/3527600043)" as a gentle introduction. This has everything you cited.

Comment: And I just noticed that the aforementioned book is not in that list, however, there are plenty of other books that may do the job as well. Somewhat related: [DFT Functional Selection Criteria](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27302/4945)